# Sync postgreSQL with SQL Server database- on data change event

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, replication, data-synchronization

I have one PostgreSQL database and its data are being changed regularly. I want to sync all its data with my SQL Server database. One thing I can do is use query to check all required tables and columns whether data is same or changed. If changed, then update the same in SQL Server.

Is there any other method is available(like replication)? Or any synchronization software available?

Answer (score 2):

1. A tool like [Daffodil Replicator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/daffodilreplica/) or [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/about/overview) is designed to sync between different brands of databases.
2. You could try the [tds_fdw](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#tds_fdw) Foreign Data Wrapper, which may be able to write to SQL Server.